# What you claim is not what you try to deliver

Tags: discussion

You claim the site is not about social chit chat, but all over the site I find information that has nothing to do with what you claim.

Posting code is a pain. I try to not post code, but then a moderator wants code, so how do I POST code if the reply to the response has no place to post code, and do I need special characters so the moderator sees my comment? KISS.

One button to reply with a comment one button to add to the first post and take the <kbd>Ask A Question</kbd> button off the bottom you lack a realistic user-friendly interface design. REALLY.

So when someone wants my code, how do I respond and post the code. Where is the button for that?

Comment: For posting code: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: This comes across as a rant. Maybe taking some time, reading the [help] and [tour] will help you understand how to use the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Also, we do the best we can to deliver what we claim. We are humans sometimes we make mistakes, but in this case, it is you finding it difficult. You haven't used the things given to you - popups, help buttons, help drop down - to solve the problem. You've come here and had a rant. That won't solve much.

Answer (score 10):

If someone is asking for your code, you need to edit it into your question:

[image]

Paste the code then select it all and click the "Format as Code" button that looks like this `{}`:

[image]

Also, a couple of points:

1. We don't like "Thank You"s in the answer. Here the way we answer is clicking the tick below the down arrow. That [accepts the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) as your chosen solution, and marks it as solved. It will be [edited out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) on most sites.
2. If you can, add the link inline. See the [formatting help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for how to do this. You can also click the link icon:

[image]

And then enter the link into the input box.

3. `not about Social Chit Chat`. This site isn't about chatting to each other. Comments are temporary, and they are often removed. However, sometimes a comment is required - to ask the user for clarification or add more information (if you're not the question owner. The question owner should always edit to include the information). This is one of the ways we can help you - we can't do it without *any* conversation.

Comment: Thanks for the drastic improvement to my answer @Tim!

Comment: it's a pleasure :P I had written it and then it was closed. Seemed a shame to let it go to waste!

Comment: Do me a favor go to the Help Center and do a search for the topic

Comment: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) Also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [this](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)